# Kafka Streams - Usage for dates based filtering

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I would like to consider using Kafka and Kafka Streams, in a java, Spring based service for the following scenario:

1. Events always published to the system. Each event holds id, time field, type and operation
2. Events rules exist in the system, there are few... and rules are published from time to time (rare)
   Each event rule includes id (different from the event itself), a date range, type and operation. 
   The goal of the event rules is to find matches on the incoming events, based on the type, operation and dates range.

I would like to answer the following cases:

1. Filter the events base on the existing event rules in runtime.
2. When a new event or an event rule is published to the system, I want to find the matches without any manual intervention...
3. I would like to have the ability to insert a new rule, with an old date range and to find matches. for example to find relevant events from the last month.

For non-streaming processing, I can think on how to find these matches in the DB, using some filtering of type, operation and dates range.
But, I'm not sure how this can be done using data pipeline architecture.

Is it reasnoable to create 2 KStream, to set a key based on type, operation and to make a join. Then, to filter based on dates range?
Is it effective in Kafka?

Any help is very appricated!

Comment: You can use filter function of Kafka Streams to grab messages of a certain range

Comment: Do you mean to join between KStream to KSTream or KStream to KTable or...?
Let's say that I have a join, then I can filter for a specific dates and to get just the relevant events...
but, in case that I would like to get results of an old data... is it efficiate to make join / filter on a lot of records... or this is not a best approache?
This is in comparison to a DB search with dates filter...

Comment: None. There is simply a filter() function on a single stream. Join isn't needed

Comment: Ok, let's say that I have more details in the event that I should match based on the event rules... this should be the first filter, then, I should also filter based on dates.
How can I filter based on other KStream / KTable

Comment: I'm not sure. A join to a KTable would require an exact match, not a range of values.

Comment: I edited my question and added more details... it would be great if someone can help me from architecture point of view.

Comment: You could also try out ksqlDB to do joins and filters

Comment: My question is more about the design of this solution, whether this is a good approach to go with Kafka Streams / Ksql or to use the "old fusion" DB queries approach.

Especially, for the 3 case (searching / filtering on old records)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you'd be joining against exactly. You've only mentioned a rules engine (a relatively static set of functions) and just one stream of events. And filtering would only be performed as events were collected, not over past data without resetting timestamps or rewinding the consumed offset

Comment: Ok, so I thought that I can stream both the events and event_rules to a two different topics, then, I'm able to make a join by setting each stream key to include type and operation (for example type + "_" + operations as a key)

The filter of the dates range can come afterwards... when in the joined stream I have just the relevant event types and operations.

Comment: Can someone please help?